# Folland Exercise 4 chapter 5

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> If $X$, $Y$ are normed vector spaces the map $(T,x)\to Tx$ is continuous from $L(X,Y)\times x$ to $Y$. (That is, if $T_n\to T$ and $x_n\to x$ then $T_n x_n \to Tx$)

My professor told me to use $\epsilon$ proof. So here is the proof:

$$\forall\epsilon>0 \ \exists N_1\in\Bbb N \text{ s.t } \forall n\ge N_1: ||T_n-T||<\epsilon/(2(||x||+1)).$$

$$\forall\epsilon>0 \ \exists N_2\in\Bbb N \text{ s.t } \forall n\ge N_2: ||x_n-x|| < \min(1,\epsilon/(2(||T||+1))).$$

Let $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$, then for $\forall n\ge N$ :

$||T_nx_n-Tx||\leq||x_n|| ||T_n-T||+||T|| ||x_n-x||$
Now here is where I am stuck. I have to get the equation $<\epsilon$ .
Suppose i plug : $||T|| \epsilon/(2(||T||+1))$ why can I cancel $||T||$ and get $<\epsilon/2$ without factoring the bottom part?

2. What is the use of 1 in $\min(1,\epsilon/(2(||T||+1)))$?

Help me to clarify it because the same technique is used everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We simply use $\displaystyle \frac A{A+1}<1$ for $A\ge0$. 
   The $+1$ in the denominator are there to ensure the statement for $\|x\|=0$ or $\|T\|=0$, and provide a uniform proof. 
   Alternatively, one can separately handle the above trivial cases, and then can omit those $+1$ in the denominators.
2. I think it's of no use at all.

Comment: Clear. Thank you!